# How to solve for matrix x?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have to find a matrix $X$ such that $AX=B$

Are my steps correct?

$$
A^{-1}(AX) = A^{-1} B \\
X= A^{-1} B
$$

Comment: This of course presupposes that A is invertible, if $A$ is not invertible, there may or may not be a solution.

Comment: If $A$ is not a $n \times n$ matrix, things get even more complicated.